# How To Upgrade Wine from 1.2 to 1.5 in Maverick 10.10

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, wine

I am using Maverick Meerkat (10.10). It has Wine 1.2. I followed the instructions at WinHQ for updating wine. In Synaptic Package Manager, the highest version I get now for upgrading is 1.3, not 1.5.

How can I get upgrade to Wine 1.5? I do not want to upgrade the Ubuntu version.

It seems that some of the supporting libraries such as lib6 are old. I would like to know how I can update them so as to make Wine 1.5 available.

**Update**: After adding the PPA, I was able to get Wine 1.4, even though Synaptic Software Manager listed it as 1.3. The reason I wanted the latest wine was to install the Encyclopedia Britannica DVD. I got it installed in Windows and started using the installation folder from Wine. Prior to that, I had to run Windows flash installer in Wine. So, this problem is already solved.

Comment: Since you are asking for help for a version of Ubuntu which is no longer supported, and the problem would be solved much more easily if you were using a newer version, it only makes me even more curious about your reasons for sticking with Maverick.  Care to enlighten?

Comment: Gnome 2 most likely than not.

Comment: I prefer this version because it uses Gnome 2 and OpenOffice. I can use Mate desktop for getting Gnome 2 effects but there is no replacement for OpenOffice. One of the books that I am writing was originally written in OpenOffice. That document suffers from formatting and stability problems in LibreOffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maverick is already EOL.

The Official Wine PPA offers Wine 1.3 for Maverick, 1.5 and 1.4 are for Oneiric and Precise *Only*, dependencies and all.

I *suppose* installing from source could be an option otherwise you'll have to upgrade.

- http://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/installing-wine-source/